# how can i transfer my android application data over network to mysql database

Tags: php, android

I have made a simple login application and i have installed that application on my android mobile..

secondly I have made a database om my laptop im mysql. of wamp server
I have connected both the mobile and laptop to same wifi..
my question is ho to transfer these username and password to mysql database..
I am also using php page to connect android app data to transfer this username password
 to mysql database..

I have the following code..

1) android code..

this is  loginpage.java code

```
package com.example.client_gps;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Loginpage extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG_UNAME="username";
    private static final String TAG_PWORD="password";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS="success";
    Button loginacc;
    EditText uname,pword;
    InputStream isr=null;
    int r;
    //JSONParser jsonParser=new JSONParser();
    String username;
    String password;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        setContentView(R.layout.loginpage);
        loginacc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login_account);
        uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernametxt);
        pword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordtxt);

        loginacc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                username=uname.getText().toString();
                password=pword.getText().toString();
                Log.e("dd","username");
                logindata();

            }
        }); 
    }
    public void logindata()
    {
        String result=null;
        Log.e("msg","inside logindata");
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //httpclient.geCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,new UsernamePasswordCredentials("root",""));
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.43.2/login.php");
        Log.e("msg","clear1");

        try
        {
        List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TAG_UNAME",username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TAG_PWORD",password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        Log.e("msg","clear2");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.e("msg","clear3");
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr= entity.getContent();
        Log.e("msg",isr.toString());
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e)
        {

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {

        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
            String line=null;
            while((line= reader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            isr.close();
            result=sb.toString();   
            Log.e("result",result);
             r=Integer.parseInt(result);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("error","error converting data");
        }

        if(r==1)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(),Homepage.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        else
        {
            Log.e("msggg11","login failed");
        }

    }
}
```

this is the php code 
data from android code is transfered to php page and then to database 
    the problem is that 
in android sdk the error is that 'Name-pc'(name of the pc) doesent have the access to mysql server , which is on the same laptop..

```
    <?php
$response=array();
{
$unm=$_POST["TAG_UNAME"];
$pwd=$_POST["TAG_PWORD"];

    $con=mysqli_connect("192.168.43.2","root","root","mydb");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo("connection failed".mysqli_connect_errno()); die();
    }

    else

    $result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from userinfo where user_name='$unm' && password='$pwd'");
    //$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from userinfo");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $resp=1;
        //$response["success"]=1;
        /*while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        $output[]=$row;
        }*/
        //echo json_encode($response);
        echo json_encode($resp);
    }
        else
        {
        $resp=0;
        echo json_encode($resp);
        }

//print(json_encode($output));
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: I think that error is not in the android SDK, but in the php code and you read it to the android, please test the php code on a browser, maybe use fiddler2 or something

Comment: ya i got the solution. the problem was in php page.. i was using wamp server and insted of giving "localhost" in mysqli connect is was giving the server address..